# Vertical center text with a fontawesome icon in a button

Tags: html, css, button, font-awesome

I am trying to vertical-align the text in a button with a font awesome icon. This is the code I tried:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"><span style="padding-top: -50px;">Sign in with</span>
<i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:3em;"></i></button>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/koh8jkyb/

`line-height` is also not working. What's the problem here?

Comment: try `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`

Comment: But that makes the icon to go to new line http://jsfiddle.net/koh8jkyb/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/koh8jkyb/5/

Answer (score 0):

just use vertical-align:middle with the icon

Answer (score 0):

Use `style="font-size:3em;vertical-align:middle;"`

Check out the running code at http://jsfiddle.net/koh8jkyb/

Comment: Please add more info on your actual solution; don't just post JSFiddle links!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
<span style="padding: 10px;display: block;float: left;">Sign in with</span>
<i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:3em;float: right;"></i>
</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/koh8jkyb/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS :

```
.center-content {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;

}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="center-content">Sign in with</span>
    <span class="center-content">
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:3em;"></i>
    </span>
</button>
```